# How to find the most and least used keys?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this data in my table:

```
INSERT INTO VIDEOS VALUES(20,'V1','KIDNAP','CRIME');
INSERT INTO VIDEOS VALUES(20,'V2','ABUSE','CRIME');
INSERT INTO VIDEOS VALUES(20,'V3','ROBBERY','CRIME');
INSERT INTO VIDEOS VALUES(20,'V4','MURDER','CRIME');
INSERT INTO VIDEOS VALUES(20,'V5','POLITICAL','POLITICAL');
INSERT INTO VIDEOS VALUES(20,'V6','POLITICAL','POLITICAL');
INSERT INTO VIDEOS VALUES(20,'V7','POLITICAL','POLITICAL');
INSERT INTO VIDEOS VALUES(20,'V8','POLITICAL','POLITICAL');
INSERT INTO VIDEOS VALUES(20,'V9','SOCIAL','SOCIAL');
INSERT INTO VIDEOS VALUES(19,'V1','KIDNAP','CRIME');
INSERT INTO VIDEOS VALUES(19,'V2','ABUSE','CRIME');
INSERT INTO VIDEOS VALUES(19,'V3','ROBBERY','CRIME');
INSERT INTO VIDEOS VALUES(19,'V4','MURDER','CRIME');
INSERT INTO VIDEOS VALUES(19,'V5','POLITICAL','POLITICAL');
INSERT INTO VIDEOS VALUES(19,'V6','POLITICAL','POLITICAL');
INSERT INTO VIDEOS VALUES(19,'V7','POLITICAL','POLITICAL');
INSERT INTO VIDEOS VALUES(19,'V8','POLITICAL','POLITICAL');
INSERT INTO VIDEOS VALUES(29,'V1','KIDNAP','CRIME');
INSERT INTO VIDEOS VALUES(29,'V2','ABUSE','CRIME');
INSERT INTO VIDEOS VALUES(29,'V3','ROBBERY','CRIME');
```

From the above 19, 20 and 29 are the key values. I want to find the keys having min and max number of values along with the keys.

Here key 29 has the fewest values (3) and key 20 has the most values (9).

How can I identify the least and most used keys values?

Comment: What if there's a tie?

Comment: @Cory , displays two values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have ties you can use `keep dense_rank`, or two versions of it in this case, using [`first`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions065.htm) and [`last`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions083.htm):

```
select min(id) keep (dense_rank first order by count(*)) as id_with_fewest,
  max(id) keep (dense_rank last order by count(*)) as id_with_most
from videos
group by id;

ID_WITH_FEWEST ID_WITH_MOST
-------------- ------------
            29           20
```

If you do have ties you can decide how to order them by adding another clause to the `order by` - say `order by count(*), id`.

This method won't allow you to get two results back if there is a tie though. If you need to do that you can use an inine view. Adding some data so there's a tie for the lowest count:

```
INSERT INTO VIDEOS VALUES(30,'V1','KIDNAP','CRIME');
INSERT INTO VIDEOS VALUES(30,'V2','ABUSE','CRIME');
INSERT INTO VIDEOS VALUES(30,'V3','ROBBERY','CRIME');
```

Minimum:

```
select id
from (
  select id, dense_rank() over (order by count(*)) as rnk
  from videos
  group by id
)
where rnk = 1;

        ID
----------
        30
        29
```

Maximum:

```
select id
from (
  select id, dense_rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as rnk
  from videos
  group by id
)
where rnk = 1;

        ID
----------
        20
```